# Возврат значений из функции

Tags: c++, функции

Скажите, пожалуйста, есть ли какая-то видимая разница в работе 2-х функций?

```
int & func1(int & b)
{
    return b;
}

int func2(int & b) 
{   
return b; 
}
```

С объектами классов я разобрался (про создание копий объектов, работу конструкторов копирования и деструкторов).

Как я понял, в func2 при возврате значения будет создаваться временная копия объекта и удаляться. В func1 этого происходить не будет.

Это как-то влияет на работу программы?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Немножко побуду Капитаном Очевидность. Из первой функции вы возвращаете ссылку на int, из второй - просто int. С результатом первой функции вы можете работать как со ссылкой (Кэп не даст соврать), в частности, использовать его как lvalue.

Скажем, вы можете сделать так:

```
int & func1(int & b)
{
    return b;
}

int func2(int & b) 
{   
    return b; 
}

int main() {
    int i = 10;

    // можно инкрементить результат выполнения функции
    // выглядит странновато, однако работает        
    cout << func1(i)++ << endl;     // выведет 10

    // а тут можно увидеть результат предыдущего инкремента
    cout << i << endl; // выведет 11

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Стоит отметить для полноты, что такой трюк _не_ пройдёт со второй функцией, т. к. она возвращает не lvalue.

@usk-dima: убедитесь, что вы хорошо понимаете разницу между lvalue и не-lvalue. Если нет, можно почитать, например [вот это](http://ericlippert.com/2014/05/12/what-are-the-fundamental-rules-of-pointers/).

Comment: 
Спасибо большое.
Ваше объяснение дало мне немного более понять, как происходит присвоение значения элемента.
Просто я эксперементировал следующим образом:

    int main()
    {
 int a = 3;
 int b;

 b = func1(a);
 a = 4;
 b = 5;
 cout << a << " " << b << endl;
    }

и не видел никакой разницы.

Теперь я понял, что прежде чем присвоить значение переменной b, ф-я сначала возвращает значение по ссылке, а потом происходит присваивание.

Если использовать func2, то ф-я создаёт копию объекта и уже присваивает значение этой копии b.

Я правильно понял?

Comment: @usk-dima, правильно.

Если же посмотрите на вещи более конкретно (вместо объектов и ссылок будете оперировать переменной целого типа в памяти, ее адресом, стеком для передачи аргументов и регистром для возврата результата), то понимание улучшится (IMHO).

Comment: @avp: С переменной целого типа просто, но эта конкретизация слишком упрощает положение вещей по сравнению со случаем, скажем, C++-объекта с конструктором копирования. И ещё, компилятор может заинлайнить функцию. Поэтому мне кажется, что нужно (1) иметь нужную абстракцию в голове, (2) понимать, как это реализовано на моём компиляторе с учётом возможных оптимизаций (а также исключений и т. п.).

Кроме того, [по поводу стека](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/01/13/58199.aspx).

Comment: @VladD, мне кажется, пока ученик толком не осознает, что именно делает компьютер (а он *программирует* именно конкретный компьютер, а не набор абстракций) с примитивными типами, от абстракций (объекты и т.п.) будет один вред.

--

Что же по поводу стека, то я просто для начала не стал вываливать на голову @usk-dima все соглашения о связях, которые есть (были) в разных архитектурах (ну, все-то я и сам не помню).

Comment: @avp: Тэг [c++] обязывает :(

Хотя да, учить C++ первым языком — не лучшая идея.